# how to control the position of new buffer in vim

Tags: vim, plugins, buffer

I write a vim plugin to get the weather info in python, I use  print to print weather info, all core code are wrapped in a function `Weather()`. when I call this function in vim, the weather info will be showed in a new buffer under current buffer, can I control this new buffer in the left of current buffer or any other position.

Comment: See `:h :topleft` and the related commands.

Answer (score 3):

If you plan to publish this plugin, you should honor the user's preferences (e.g. the `'splitbelow'` setting), and offer a configuration variable to influence the window placement.

Generally, there are prefix commands that influence the window placement: `:vertical`, `:leftabove`, `:rightbelow`, `:topleft`, `:botright`. They are used like this:

```
:topleft new
```

Sometimes, it may also be necessary to first go to a particular window, `:execute winnr . 'wincmd w'` can do this. And finally, many commands that split a new window can be passed an initial window height.

Comment: sorry I know not so much about vimscript. I try to below two ways: 1. run command in vim, :vertical topleft call Weather() 2. run command in plugin, vim.command('vertical topleft vsplit') . ||| ALL two ways failed. weather info still be showed in the default bottom buffer. could you please give some detail command about how to call the function Weather() in vim or use some vimscript trick

Comment: Just prepending before `:call` won't do; you need to find the `:split` / `:new` command _inside_ your `Weather()` function and prepend it there. `:topleft vsplit` should work (the `:vertical` is already contained in the `vsplit`).

Comment: vim.command('topleft vsplit')
    vim.command('echo "%s"'%weather)
| the weather is the text I wanna show, but still be showed in the bottom buffer

Comment: Let's be systematic for pinpointing the problem. Does it work when you execute this directly, not from Python?

Comment: sure, vim also has python interface. python <<EOF {python code} EOF

Comment: Sorry, was that confirmative?! For me, the following works as well: `:python vim.command('topleft vsplit')`

Comment: alright, maybe I confused you, sorry, I mean redirect the output to a special buffer.